# How do I save code snippets to a database?

Tags: python, django, markdown, pagedown

I'm creating a Django website for game developers to share code, which means I need to be able to save properly formatted code to a database, as well as being able to retrieve and display it.

Is there anything built into Django for this, or do I need to use a third party library?

I've played with a Django [pagedown widget](https://github.com/timmyomahony/django-pagedown), which is modeled after StackOverflow's markdown editor, but I've had some trouble with it, and I'm not positive if that's is going to accomplish everything I want by itself.

Has anyone actually used the pagedown widget, implemented functionality similar to this, or know of another library that would work?

Comment: Yes, check out the Django docs page on [Databases](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/databases/). You'll need to install and configure whatever database you are going to use, and then you'll need to install and use a "driver" to have Django interact with the database.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For storing the code, you can use any database that supports text types. That is, you would use a [TextField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/fields/#textfield) in your model.

Now you need to decide how that raw text will be displayed/formatted.

This depends on what you mean by displaying properly formatted code, but I'm going to go ahead and just say you should check out [Pygments](http://pygments.org/). It is a syntax highlighting library that can be easily used w/Django.

Pygments works by your specifying a lexer (read: language) for it to apply styling to the target text. Whitespace will be preserved by your database. Everything else formatting-related is purely subjective. You'd presumably specify a fixed width font, a size, etc in the view and pass it to the context as you would any other DB-backed object.

[Django Rest Framework's tutorial](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/1-serialization/) actually makes something very similar to what you are describing and uses Pygments, so I'd recommend checking that out for concrete usage examples.

For formatting code exclusively, I would avoid any markdown flavors like the one you listed, as code could contain characters that have special meaning in markdown, thus you would need to escape the text, and that defeats the purpose of markdown.